# TortoiseSVN keeps stalling/hanging

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm reorganising my repository by using TortoiseSVN to do move folders in my working copy, to avoid having to re-download the whole thing if I make the changes in the repo directly. However the "Moving..." popup seems to just stay around for ever in many cases, even when the dir being moved has few files. The files seem to be moved ok, except if I kill the process then I have to do SVN cleanup every time.

I don't like killing processes working on my working copy, but I can't find what's wrong. My Tortoise is pretty recent; do I need to use Tortoise of exactly the same version as the SVN repo or anything weird like that?

One of the main problems is even when it is doing something, the "Moving..." dialog doesn't indicate this. It's supposed to show current progress but is usually totally out of sync or never updates at all.

EDIT: I don't think it can be a connection problem. The problems are all doing local SVN move operations... once I get those to work committing the changes to the remote server are just fine.

Also, TortoiseSVN is killing my whole XP machine while it sits there. The hard-disk is thrashing and although Task-manager says my CPU usage is ~5%, other apps simply stop responding (such as Chrome)

Comment: More info is needed. What OS, what platform, what kind of connection, where is the repository located etc.

Comment: When making major changes to our repo, which I do as rarely as I possibly can, I use the CLI.  Like you I have experienced long delays in TortoiseSVN finishing some operations such as moving things around. FWIW we have our repo hosted on a Windows server of some vintage or other on the local network.  We all generally use TortoiseSVN for everyday operations, only the admin (me) is likely to get down and dirty with the CLI.  I use a Cygwin terminal window for doing this.

Answer (score 8):

[Try turning off Tortoise's status cache under "Icon Overlays".](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-overlay)

Mine was so slow, I actually uninstalled it and now I just use svn from the command line.
However, you might get some relief by setting the cache to "None"

Answer (score 5):

Try disabling the icon overlays if they are not already, especially if you're working off a network drive.

In explorer:
right-click > Tortoise SVN > Settings

Select Icon Overlays on left hand column
Set Status Cache to NONE.

Add wildcard of entire drive to Exclude Paths: [drive letter]:*

Add specifically the paths you use SVN for: [drive and path]:*

Comment: This is working for me on an old version 1.9.5. I don't know if the problem exists on newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion pre 1.6.3 had some memory problems (huge memory usage for certain operations). If you're still using such a client, you should consider updating to the latest version.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.6.x/CHANGES

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the folder that you are moving has been "**SVN-Update**"-ed before moving it. If it is not up to date it will hang which I have encountered with version 1.8.7.

The problem with using Tortoise SVN to move items is that when problems occur you cannot see it. Therefore i.m.h.o. it is a good consideration to use the command line for this.

As an addition for people not familiar with it: you can move items by dragging them with the *right mouse button*. Then select "**SVN Move selected item(s) here**".

Answer (score 0):

Solve this by **only including directories with your code**. In the link provided by @nont, there is an image with `C:\` being excluded. https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-overlay

**Example:** I have a computer with `C:\` and `D:\` drives. All of my code lives under `C:\foo\`. Using this as an example, Add the following to "TortoiseSVN Setting -> Icon Overlay"

```
Excluded Paths:
C:\
D:\

Included Paths:
C:\foo\
```

After applying the changes, you should see immediate improvements.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it stood stuck while I used the network drive.

I fixed that issue while moving my repo to drive `C:\` instead.